# Writing to a file based on contents of EditText

Tags: android, file-io

I am having problems writing to a file, when an EditText is empty I want to write a single space character or `-` in my file but my conditions are simply ignored.

This isn't working and I don't understand why:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isthereafile == true){
            questioncount++;
            questiontext = question.getText().toString();
            correctanswertext = correctanswer.getText().toString();
            wronganswertext1 = wronganswer1.getText().toString();
            wronganswertext2 = wronganswer2.getText().toString();
            textpathofpic = pathofpic.getText().toString();

            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(test,true);

                if(question.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
                writer.append(questiontext + ";");}
                if(correctanswer.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
                writer.append(correctanswertext + ";");}
                if(wronganswer1.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
                writer.append(wronganswertext1 + ";");}
                if(wronganswer2.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
                writer.append(wronganswertext2 + ";");}
                if(pathofpic.getText().toString().equals("") == false){
                writer.append(textpathofpic + ";");}

                if(question.getText().toString().equals("")){writer.append("-");}
                if(correctanswer.getText().toString().equals("")){writer.append("-");}
                if(wronganswer1.getText().toString().equals("")){writer.append("-");}
                if(wronganswer2.getText().toString().equals("")){writer.append(" ");}
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();     
                question.setText("");           
                correctanswer.setText("");      
                wronganswer1.setText("");           
                wronganswer2.setText("");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: The first obvious thought is that `isthereafile` is false - have you tried stepping through with the debugger, or logging the values?

Comment: Thanks for your help but on the onClick methond isthereafile become true,this is when an user push Back button and dosnt click on "OK" on the dialog,against crash etc...

Comment: Instead of removing the code and commenting that you fixed it, for the benefit of future visitors, it's generally more desirable to simply add an answer of your own explaining how you fixed it and then accept that answer. I've rolled back your edit to give you the opportunity to do that.

Comment: what do you mean by "button and dosnt click on "OK" on the dialog,against crash etc"... what is against crash etc?

Comment: ok sorry i have to wait 8 hours before i can answer @raju i will explain on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
  question.getText().toString().equals("")
```

try like this

```
  question.getText().toString().length()==0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the text in addition to checking the length:

```
if (question.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
}
```

A much larger problem is that your code writes to the file system on the main thread. You also don't close the FileWriter in a finally block. And there is no need to call flush() immediately before close().